# Python turtle wait for spacebar

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I just discovered the turtle module, and I'm trying to use it. I'd like to run a program that draws a static graphic, and then close the window when the space bar is pressed. This program draws the graphic just fine – but then nothing happens when I press the – and fairly soon the blue wheel is spinning, and the window has become unresponsive in the mind of Windows.

How to do better? How to wait while remaining a "responsive window"?

Python 3.9,
Windows 10

```
import turtle
from time import sleep
t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.onkey(turtle.bye, ' ') 


t.forward(150)
t.rt(108)


while True:
    sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to the `listen()` method so your key press won't be *heard*.  Also, don't reinvent the event loop -- neither `while True:` nor `sleep()` belong in an event-driven world like turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.forward(150)
turtle.right(108)

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(screen.bye, ' ')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had missed the existence of mainloop().